# How to list Magento sub categories and their products on category/view.phtml

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.4

I am pretty new to magento and have gotten my design implemented, but I am struggling with a category/product listing issue.

My categories are like this

```
Parent
   Child
      Grandchild 1
         Product 1
         Product 2
      Grandchild 2
         Product 1
         Product 2
```

I have the top level nav with a drop down listing the children available on all pages, but once you navigate to the child I want it to list each grandchild category and the relevant products.

The store is going to be kept pretty small so we're talking about 5-10 products per grandchild category.

The site is at http://gasworksparkkiteshop.com any advice would be massively helpful.  I am also using customizing a copy of the Modern theme.

Comment: BTW, the front page of that site is lots of fun.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look in your theme's `catalog.xml` file. You should find something like this,

```
<catalog_category_default translate="label">
    <label>Catalog Category (Non-Anchor)</label>
    <reference name="left">
        <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/navigation/left.phtml"/>
    </reference>
    ...
```

Your site doesn't have a left block that I can see so the above code does nothing. Try changing the reference to a location that is in use, or in the `2columns-right.phtml` insert the errant left column where you want the navigation block to appear.

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('left') ?>
```

Comment: I have played with this and must be missing something.  I can't get it to list the sub categories or the products in that sub... If you look at the link, there are Single line kites, go to Easy kites, that page us using the category/view.phtml and I am using the 2column_left page... The goal is to have the heading EASY Kites, then list the related sub categories to Easy Kites, then inside the list of sub categories it will list the products related to the sub.  Homepage > Single Line Kites > Easy Kites > list all sub categories and products